# Access to account team member object

Tags: security, custom-profile, salesfoce, config

I have a custom profile and the assigned user is not able to see buttons 'Add Default Team', 'Add Team Members' etc. At the time of creating custom profile I had given only Read, Edit permissions on Account object and removed View All and Modify all permissions. When I give the Modify all on account, It will show me the Account Team buttons obviously but, I do not want that. What am I missing? Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Can the user of the profile modify a particular account where they are trying to add the team. This might have to do something with record level security.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.accountteam_add.htm&type=5) Account team access is only visible if the user having below access,

- Edit access on account record.
- User is an Account owner or User need to available in above/parent Role of the Account owner's role in Role hierarchy.

Please let me know if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Edit is already there.
2. This is for any user who has that custom profile assigned.
3. I can compare the Role hierarchy. Thanks for that insight.

Comment: I have checked the Roles. There is no difference. 'Modify All' actually works but it automatically checks 'Delete' which I do not want now. There is something else.

Comment: @vishnu.b Hi, May I know the issue affected user already available in higher role(compare to account owner) and unable to view account teams in account record?

Comment: The affected user currently does not any role assigned.

Comment: Oh..If you're org doesn't follow role hierarchies means, it's will be difficult to answer your question, Because based on the docs this access required role permission. So May be you can assign the role and check (in your sandbox) then decide is it okay for you.

Comment: Thanks @mohanraj

Comment: Turns out that running the apex class in 'without sharing' mode worked for me